# mail (postfix) not running in launchAgent unless followed by another command

Tags: bash, launchd, postfix-mta

I'm running a user LaunchAgent in El Cap that is supposed to call postfix to send me an email when a certain automatically generated file is 0 length, meaning that something went wrong. Here's the line from the bash script where $me is my username:

```
echo 'Darn it' | mail -s 'Export failed' "$me"
```

It works fine if I run the script manually, but mail won't send anything when the agent runs.

By dumb luck I found that if I follow this command with the following command, the message will get sent:

```
/usr/local/bin/terminal-notifier -message "File export failed." -title "Alert"
```

Other following commands won't do it (like echo, for example).

Any idea what's going on there?

Comment: Start by adding the full path to the mail command in your script. Then try and output the launch agent process to a file to monitor the progress or try and run it to the foreground.

Comment: I already tried the full path. No change. How do I run it to the foreground? And I'm not sure what you mean about outputting it to a file. I already had an `echo` immediately following the mail command which I piped to an error log. That made no difference.